# Web Pages dynamically generated drop down?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I am currently utilizing the Microsoft WebMatrix IDE to develop a website that will display information from a database. The issue that I am trying to address is how to create a drop down that will pull data from a database and display it as individual items in the list. For example it will have one drop down showing the unique buildings in the database and another showing the unique rooms in each building. I found the method for doing this in the MVC, but it is not applicable in WebMatrix.

Answer (score 1):

This Mike Brind's article should help you to dinamically create a second drop down with Ajax: [WebMatrix - jQuery Cascading Dropdown Lists](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/196/WebMatrix-jQuery-Cascading-Dropdown-Lists).